# Newsfeed with MongoDB with user actions

Tags: mysql, django, mongodb

I'm building a system where users can interact with various activities (buddies, events, etc.). I'm thinking of using mongodb for this, and have done a decent amount of work already. i also read the below, which is similar to what i'm thinking:

[Constructing a personalized Facebook-like Newsfeed: SQL, MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491862/constructing-a-personalized-facebook-like-newsfeed-sql-mongodb)

My concern is this... Say a user is interacting with an event of some sort, currently the data for the event is in MySQL. If the user later on updates parts of the event (specifically the title), is there a quicker way to update the newsfeed item that has the title in it? I'm storing the title as a json message for the activity stream...